# Lack of vs A lack of

Tags: indefinite-articles

Are there any differences between the uses/meanings of "lack of" and "a lack of" for example in the following?

1. There is a lack of interest in the topic
2. There is lack of research on the subject

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In OP's particular example I think there's no doubt the article would normally be included, but there's nothing particularly unusual about the version without it.

But I do think there's a stronger case for saying that in constructions where "the/a lack" is the grammatical *subject*, including the article stands out as "idiomatically uncommon". The easiest way I can think of to illustrate this is through Google Books...

> [but lack of funding (caused the project to founder)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but%20lack%20of%20funding%22) - about 1490 written instances
>    [but **a** lack of funding (etc.)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but%20lack%20of%20funding%22#tbm=bks&q=%22but%20a%20lack%20of%20funding%22) - about 532 hits

As implied, that disparity is just a quirk of established idiomatic preference. I don't think there are any contexts where there could be a *semantic* difference.

Comment: Yes, I'd say _existential there_ renders the zero article option less idiomatic.

Comment: @Edwin: I really don't know whether it's a matter of *existential there* as such, or simply that consequently *the/a **lack*** won't be the syntactic subject in such a construction anyway. It's only an idiomatic preferrence, and not *that* consistently observed, so I don't know how much further one could take this issue.

Comment: Hey, I'm agreeing with you (it's getting near Christmas).

Comment: @Edwin: Hey, I'm certainly not *disagreeing* with you! I was kinda hoping I might tickle you into either telling me more about what you *already* know, or doing some spade-work / thinking to figure out something *neither* of us yet knows. My second sentence above was just by way of saying it's not that important if you can't or don't want to bother. (Whatever - "Merry Christmas", if it's not [too soon](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=too%20soon) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for the answer. Although both uses sound fine to me, I feel there are subtleties that are not too easy to establish.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the skew persists for dummy it constructions. [These](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+a+lack+of%2Cit+was+lack+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20a%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20lack%20of%3B%2Cc0) ...  [Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+a+fear+of%2Cit+was+fear+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20a%20fear%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20fear%20of%3B%2Cc0) Ngrams seem to support this view. However, ...

Comment: I can also find ones where the article is preferred. Certain mass-or-are-they nouns ([it was] an acceptance [of]; [it was] a desire [for]

 seem more likely to sit comfortably next to an indefinite article than others ([it was] support [for]; [it was] love [of]). [Of course, there may be noise in these results.] (**PS** It may be nearly Christmas, but  '... I might tickle you into ... doing some spade-work' is pushing it.)

Answer (score 2):

The use of the indefinite article indicates singularity. "A lack of"indicates " a particular lack of"(Thefreedictionary.com).If you use "lack of"you refer to "lack or absence in a general way. Your examples require "a".